# Dynamically changing the width an element in Angular

Tags: css, angular

Forgive me, I'm new to Angular.

I'm trying to dynamically change the a div when a button is clicked. I have tried `[style.width]` and `[style.width.px]`. and it seems to work initially setting the value, but when I try to change it within a function it doesn't seem to be rendering on the screen. Meaning, it changes in the html, but not visually. I have been staring at this too long so some hep would be appreciated.

The div in the html

```
<div class='logo-contain' [style.width]='logoWidth'>stuff</div>
```

Where the initial variable is set in the ts file

```
 logoWidth = '450px';
```

And the function within the ts file

```
closeSideMenu(){
    if(my conditional){
        this.logoWidth = '50px;'
    }else{
        this.logoWidth = '250px;'
    }
  }
```

Comment: it will be always true :(

Comment: @xdeepakv, yes I just replaced. my real conditional with that. I'll replace it to just say conditional

Comment: Try with `this.logoWidth = '250px';`. The semi-colon should not be included in the string. Alternatively, use `[style.width.px]="logoWidth"`, with `this.logoWidth = 250;`. There is no reason to use `[ngStyle]` to set a single style property.

Comment: The `[style.width]` notation should work. Can you provde a stackblitz of the problem? How do you call `closeSideMenu`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ngStyle`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

```
<div class='logo-contain' [ngStyle]='{ width : logoWidth }'>stuff</div>
```

---

Even `[style.width` need to work, that `;` may cause the problem so remove it and try.

```
closeSideMenu(){
    if(my conditional){
        this.logoWidth = '50px'
    }else{
        this.logoWidth = '250px'
    }
  }
```

Or alternately you can provide pixel value binding `style.width.px`

```
<div class='logo-contain' [style.width.px]='logoWidth'>stuff</div>

closeSideMenu(){
    if(my conditional){
        this.logoWidth = 50
    }else{
        this.logoWidth = 250
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason why ngStyle works in the case and not style.width?

Comment: @zazvorniki : try `[style.width.px] ="logoWidth"` and value without px, like `logoWidth = 50`'

Answer (score 0):

the issue with value: by mistake u added semi-colon `;` at end of the value, `50px;` remove ';'. Best use, `[ngStyle]`

```
closeSideMenu(){
    if(my conditional){
        this.logoWidth = '50px;'
    }else{
        this.logoWidth = '250px;'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Even with removing that it didn't want to change. Not really sure why. The ngStyle seems to wok though :)

Comment: it works.. https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-shirley-xhyb8

Comment: I thinks than u doing something fisshy :-D